# How to set text in a textview which is in a layout, that has bee referenced in 'Preferences' file in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a preferences settings xml file, in which I have referenced another layout. (android:layout="@layout/things") . Now I want to add a text to the textview that is present in "things" layout from the activity that extends preference activity. how to do it? I tried like this,

```
   LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.things,null);
   TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.t_name);
   name.setText("furniture");
```

But the text is not set, its just empty? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a reference to that button inside your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //.........

 TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_name);
 name.setText("furniture");
```

Assuming you are referencing the `android:layout="@layout/things"` inside the `<Preference>` tag, all views inside "things" should be accessible from this scope

Comment: What you said is right, I m using it inside preference tag . I have tried this before itself, it ends up in null pointer exception.